# PHP Facebook SDK 5.0 api

Tags: php, facebook

I have some problem using FB-SDK-api-5.0.
I trying to get access token like this

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXX',
    'app_secret' => 'YYY',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

But $accessToken == NULL. I don't understand how to get token that will help me to use "Retrieve User Profile" method. Do you have any solution guys?

Comment: Are you loading the page inside Facebook Canvas?

Comment: Have you authorized the user before, by sending them to the login dialog?